# Django formset error

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to setup line items as a formset in django ( charges) to add to a work-order. I've tried adding the field directly into modelformset_factory in ChargesCreateView, but still nothing ( even though i already have fields set in my forms.py ).

the error is

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /workorders/charges/create/1219/
Using ModelFormMixin (base class of ChargesCreateView) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited.
```

**view.py**

```
class ChargesCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    # form_class = LineitemForm
    LineitemFormSet = modelformset_factory(Lineitem,form=LineitemForm)
    formset = LineitemFormSet()
    template_name = 'workorders/form_create_charges.html'
    success_url   = '/workorders/'

    def get_initial(self):
       return { 'workorder': self.kwargs.get('pk'),}

    def get_queryset(self):
        workorders = Workorder.objects.all().values()
        return workorders
```

**model.py**

```
class Lineitem(models.Model):
    workorder       = models.ForeignKey('Workorder', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sku             = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description     = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    qty             = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    unit_price      = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    discount        = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    amount          = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sku
```

**forms.py**

```
class LineitemForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Lineitem
        fields = [
            'workorder',
            'sku'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'workorder': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

**form_create_charges.html**

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table border="0">
                    {{ formset.management_form }}
                    {{formset}}
                </table>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> | <a href="{% url 'workorders:index' %}">Cancel</a>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using generic.CreateView, maybe try using just FormView. CreateView creates a form object based off of the model and fields specified which is why it's wanting you to add a fields variable.

Comment: If i set it to a FormView 

i get the error 
'NoneType' object is not callable, any ideas?